# How to compute a radius around a point in an Android MapView?

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview

I have a [MapView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) that I'm displaying a "useful radius" (think accuracy of coordinate) in. Using `MapView`'s [Projection](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection.html)'s [metersToEquatorPixels](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection.html#metersToEquatorPixels%28float%29), which is admittedly just for equatorial distance) isn't giving me an accurate enough distance (in pixels). How would you compute this if you wanted to display a circle around your coordinate, given radius?

Comment: This could also, probably, be stated as: I have a GPS coordinate and a distance, how can I draw a circle that encompasses the radius from the GPS point?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem - what do you mean when you say that it's not giving you an accurate enough distance?  That you meant for it say 100m but it only shows a circle at 50m or something?

Comment: Yes. It's off by a significant amount.

Comment: Actually the metersToRadius function fails badly, I tested it by using a mapview and drawing a circle when clicking a location.
I'm not good in math, the formula needs an expert ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So, Google Maps uses a [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). This means that the further you get from the equator the more distorted the distances become. According to [this discussion](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16075), the proper way to convert for distances is something like:

```
public static int metersToRadius(float meters, MapView map, double latitude) {
    return (int) (map.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(meters) * (1/ Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude))));         
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I had a query about this equation. Is this equation heavy enough to slow the performance of an app? Just curious.

Comment: The only possibly time consuming part of the formula is the Math.cos(). You can use the android.util.FloatMath.cos() function to speed things up, or even keep a table of precomputed factors, e.g. for every full degree. Then you could just say 
return (int) (map.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(meters) * factor[(int)latitude].

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.addCircle(
    new CircleOptions().center(
        new LatLng(
            bounds.getCenter().latitude, 
            bounds.getCenter().longitude
        )
    )
    .radius(50000)
    .strokeWidth(0f)
    .fillColor(0x550000FF)
);
```

Comment: The answer requires formatting and add a bit more context on how your code works and how does it solve the problem of OP!

Answer (score -2):

```
projection.toPixels(GeoP, pt);
float radius = projection.metersToEquatorPixels(50);
```

Try this and see... i used it on my MapRadius and it seems to be working

Comment: If you see my answer you'll see exactly why this won't work in all cases.